# Measuring joy and surface delight of your product

Tags: microinteractions, metrics, emotion

Say you had an APP (e.g. a mobile or webapp) and the core UX was good, and all the key tasks could be completed with ease. Say you then wanted to introduce a load of nice interactions, transitions, motion, etc, to increase 'joy and delight' of the experience, then how would you go about measuring that?

I'm thinking of maybe some attitudinal metrics in the same way you'd ask 'how easy or how hard did you find that task' could you ask some other questions to come up with benchmarks to record an improvement in 'joy and delight'. I'm not sure what to ask really, assuming sliding scales are the way to go? Can you ask something like 'how exciting or boring did you find that experience, 'how good or bad did you find the experience. They don't sound ideal - I'm at a loss TBH. Any suggestions on approach or wording would be great.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft's Desirability Testing framework](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/microsoft-desirability-toolkit/) might be a helpful method. You would show your research participants [a set of positive and negative words](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/desirability-reaction-words/) and ask them to pick the five words that most closely describe your app.

You would then cluster the results and rank them by frequency.

[From Nielsen-Norman Group:](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/microsoft-desirability-toolkit/)

> To analyze your participants’ responses, determine the percentage of participants who selected each individual word, then rank the words to identify the most frequently selected ones.
>
> Report the top most-selected words (for example, ‘calm,’ ‘expensive,’
> ‘innovative,’ ‘fresh,’ and ‘intimidating’).
>
> Use percentages rather than raw frequencies to report the number of
> times each word was selected. (For example, you may report that 71% of
> participants selected the word ‘fresh’ to describe the design.)
>
> If you have multiple user groups and can identify those in your
> participant responses, include them in the presentation of your
> results. Meaningful differences between the sets of words preferred by
> the two groups may give you insight into their different attitudes.
> (For example, you may report that 54% of experienced users described
> the design as ‘exciting’ while only 13% of novice users selected the
> same word.)
>
> If you’re evaluating multiple designs or multiple versions of the same
> design (for example, old and new), look at the differences between the
> sets of words chosen to describe the different designs. (For example,
> you may report that 83% of the users described the redesigned app as
> ‘professional,’ compared with only 20% using the same word for the
> older version of the app.)
>
> If the site is intended to communicate specific brand attributes,
> decide in advance what words correspond to your brand positioning.
> Then count how many users include at least one of those words in their
> top-5 list.
>
> Use a Venn diagram to present how your results map to design direction
> words, how different designs are described differently, or how
> different user groups describe a design differently (see the example
> below).
>
> [image: Venn diagram of words]

Comment: Oh wow, this is great. I had no idea this existed.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at Google's HEART framework, which looks at Key Experience Indicators and stands for Happiness, Engagement, Adoption, Retention and Task success. This is an article by Tomer Sharon specifically about [measuring user happiness](https://tsharon.medium.com/measuring-user-happiness-d00c941f5365).

You might also find this question interesting: [Is the Kano model adaptable for measuring user experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/42853/is-the-kano-model-adaptable-for-measuring-user-experience?rq=1).

Comment: This is also useful. The examples suggest asking a 'how happy did that make you' type questions but with only 3 options. Happy, undecided, unhappy.